# Como usar el While con un Service AngujarJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

tengo el siguiente problema, espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un bucle while y dentro estoy llamando un service, el lio es que el bucle corre muchas veces y nunca entra al service, llega a bloquear al navegador y no entra al service, si quito el while si entra.
Saben que me falta?

```
while (termina === false) {
  HorasExtrasService.ValidaDia(vm.detalle.HeFecha)
      .then(function (data) {
        if (data !== '' && moment(vm.detalle.HeFecha, 'YYYY-MM-DD').day() === 0) {
              domingo = 'S';
   }
```

esa es una parte del codigo, no lo pego todo pq es mut largo, el hecho es que no entra a llamar el service, Agradezco enormemente ayuda o guia en este proceso.

Comment: Ok, si entra en el bucle el servicio si se ejecutará, lo que quizás no veas los resultados porque el navegador no puede hacer las 5000 peticiones al mismo tiempo (usualmente es 4-8 el limite y este es configurable, los servidores también crean límites). Creo que debes cambiar la lógica de tu programa para reducir la cantidad de llamadas lo menos posible, de preferencia a una sola y eliminar el `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que la invocacion es asincrona, se invoca y continua la ejecucion hasta que el servicio responda ingresando en el then(), por lo tanto puedes tener varias llamadas en paralelo

O sea al usar un while pudiste realizar varias invocaciones y despues de varios ciclos recibir la primer respuesta.

Comment: Hola Leandro Tuttini, justo eso pasa, realiza mas de 5000 iteraciones y primero se bloquea el navegador antes que entrar al servicio (si ejecuto el servicio solo no toma mas de 1 segundo en responder). Siendo asi cual seria la forma correcta de realizarlo desde javascript??

Comment: lo correcto seria que unas los 5mil valores en una array json y crees un servicio en donde puedas enviar todos estos valores, el servidor los procesa y devuelve una lista con la respuesta para cada valor. Entonces realizas uan sola llamada para resolver todo en una sola operacion

Comment: Hola Leandro, pero el problema seria el mismo, ya que al usar el while no me lee el servicio ya que como te indico, me hace mas de 5000 iteraciones y no entra al servicio para hacer el llamado de datos.

Comment: es que deberias dejar de usar el while, o al menos no invocar el service dentro de este. El while lo usarias para armar al array json pero cuando sales de este invocas al servicio pasandole la lista con todos los valores, en la respuesta sigues el proceso de los resultados que el servicio devuelva

Comment: ahh entiendo, no se deben usar servicios dentro de un while. Tendre que ver como lo hago entonces, ya que debo hacer un proceso mientras que una variable este falsa, y la unica que me cambia ese estado es el servicio luego de unas validaciones, si hago eso del lado del servidor seria mejor?? osea en una webapi .net que consume esa app javascrpt?

Comment: en un cliclo como el que planteas es muy veloz como para darle tiempo a que la llamada al servidor responda, quizas si realizas algun ciclo recursivo en donde invocas al servicio esperas la respuesta y validas si vuelves a llamar a si mismo para una nueva validacion, seria simil al while solo que esperas la respuesta. Igual si esto mismo podrias validarlo del lado del servidor en la webapi mucho mejor

Comment: Muchas Gracias Leandro, todo claro :)